# Which subspaces are considered in the Bubnov-Galerkin method?

Tags: functional-analysis, galerkin-methods

A PDE problem in the form
$$−∇⋅(k(x)∇u)=f$$
can be expressed in the form
$$Au=f$$
where the linear operator $A$ is defined by the expression
$$Au=−∇⋅(k(x)∇u)$$
In the Bubnov-Galerkin method, $u$ is approximated by $\bar{u}$ as a linear combination of functions taken from a subspace $\phi$.
$$\bar{u} = c_1\phi_1 + c_2\phi_2 + ... + c_n\phi_n$$
and the problem is restated in the weak form
$$\int_\Omega−∇⋅(k(x)∇\bar{u})⋅\phi\ d\Omega=\int_\Omega f⋅\phi\ d\Omega$$
In terms of the operator A, this can be expressed as
$$\phi^TA\bar{u} = \phi^Tf= \phi^TAu$$
or
$$\phi^TA(\bar{u}-u) = 0$$
This means that the image of $\bar{u}$ under $A$ is the orthogonal projection of $f$, the image of $u$ under $A$, onto space $\phi$, and in that sense is the best approximation of $u$.

I'm familiar with basic linear algebra but not with functional analysis, and I get confused when I try to imagine the subspaces involved in this method.  Specifically, it's not clear to me whether $\bar{u} \in \phi \implies A\bar{u} \in \phi$.  I believe that's not the case for $A$ because that's not generally the case for the differentiation operator.  That's my first question.  The second one is: assuming that $A\bar{u} \notin \phi$ and $A\bar{u} \in \psi$, wouldn't finding $\bar{u}$ such that $\psi^TA\bar{u} = 0$ give a better approximation?

[image: Bubnov-Galerkin subspaces imagined by OP]

Comment: If you can find a basis of eigenfunctions of $A$, that'll address your first question.

Comment: You should be able to find a basis since $A$ is uniformly elliptic and symmetric